# Generate Linux executable on QtCreator

Tags: linux, windows, qt-creator

I'm working under Windows and I'm looking for a simple solution that could make me able to cross compile for both Windows and Linux.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528499/qt-creator-cross-platform-compiling) topic :

But the reference of the answer is broken and I don't understand it very well.

I'm using QtCreator and what I want is a kit with  something that gives me a Windows executable and another kit with which I would have a executable for Linux.

So far I've been using the Visual Studio compiler MSVC on one kit. That gives me a compilation for Windows.
I'm using MinGW with GCC on another kit. I hoped it could give me a Linux executable. But this gives me a Windows executable too.

How can I get a compiler that could work under QtCreator on Windows and generate Linux executable ?

Comment: The simplest way is to install and use a Linux distribution on your machine (hence avoiding *cross*- compiling)

Comment: Yeah, but what if I don't install a Linux distrib ?

Comment: Then you are more in trouble and need to do incredibly complex things. But the choice is yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution a long time ago so I'm posting it. Maybe it could be useful.

I've used Cygwin and Crosstools. This makes me able to cross-compile for Linux while being under Windows.